# Reading redo logs from one instance of Oracle and add to another

Tags: oracle, logging, redo

Hello there I am new in Database. I want to read **redo logs** from one instance of Oracle and want's to stored that transactions in new Datasource.

I know that **GOLDEN GATE** is there to read change data capture. I want to read it from any other technology.

Please help me on this.

Comment: There is Oracle Data Guard, SharePlex... but SO is not the place to ask for recommendation of tools, products, etc

Comment: Basically I am trying to read it by using JAVA or SCALA and Spark. But I am  not understanding that, is it very hard to read redo logs?

Comment: _is it very hard to read redo logs_? YES. It is proprietary format.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "...any other technology..." redologs are binary files and you can not read them with any other tools except Oracle Tools. You can use Golden Gate, or native DataGuard technology (standby), Database Replay. 
I am not sure but most probably you want LogMiner (this is also Oracle tool, see more info here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm)

Comment: any other technology.. means actually I am trying to read redo logs by using JAVA. But I am not understanding that in which format redo log binary files are written.

Comment: You will not be able to read it with JAVA. Well - you can open and read it but the information is in binary format and not documented by Oracle - so the information useless for you (your application). In general Oracle write in the log-file so called "change vector" you can read some info about it in Oracle Docs, but it is not described in details.